# FileMaker PHP project. Use CodeIgniter, CAKE or custom-coded PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, filemaker

I'm an advanced FM developer who has done a lot of WordPress templating and some basic PHP coding.  I'm working on project that will end up needing PHP access to the FM database.  My last web project was with Lasso 4 and I'm new to PHP on the FM-side.  Thus I'm wondering whether it's worth investing in learning a PHP framework for this project.

The project is a "basic" quotes system, where suppliers can login to their accounts, enter their supplies in a quote form, and submit the form to a system which inevitably syncs/talks with a FM-inventory system in-house.

Any advice from all the wizards here is GREATLY appreciated.

TIA,
Denis

Answer (score 2):

Well, using a Framework would be a good option and since CodeIgniter is a beginners Framework in that it can be worked out easily as compared to othe frameworks, i would suggest you using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Agreed, and you can write the models to use the FileMaker php classes to work with your data.

Comment: I find Cake more a beginner framework (more automatic etc). But thats subjective. In any case: I agree that some framework should be used (Coding projects without it usually end up in a mess)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Got CI installed and have set up FX.PHP.  Can't get it to work as it looks like old code names have been changed a la `class MyExampleClass extends Controller` doesn't work but `class MyExampleClass extends CI_Controller` does!

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation.  I chose to go with CodeIgniter because someone wrote a wrapper for the FX.php class.  It's provided me with several successful projects using CI with FileMaker as the backend. Here's the original [CI Wiki post](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/FilemakerPro_Database_Integration). I'd be happy to provide some examples.

CodeIgniter was the simplest framework for me to get my head around (have also used it for several PHP/MySQL projects) and you already know FileMaker if that has to be your back-end. Only thing I haven't done is tried ODBC instead of the XML interface. Hope this helps.

UPDATE

To follow up, I have since used ODBC on at least 8-10 projects in the last few months.  Once you get over th quirks of FileMaker's ODBC driver, it's much more portable that using FX.php, and although I haven't tested the new speed of FM12, ODBC is much faster.  Just watch out for incompatible field types, query issues, and read through the FM documentation for specifics on dates, etc.

Comment: I'd absolutely love to see the CI examples with FileMaker as I just couldn't get it to work @user1150789

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [comparisona of php frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP), and decide yourself if any of those is worthy enough to waste some time for to use for your new project.

Comment: Thanks, CI looks like it will do once I finally get it up and running!